# Redirecting HTTP request through Websocket tunnel

Tags: java, websocket, jboss, cloud, undertow

I just want to know, is it possible a web server (JBOSS - Undertow) can redirect an incoming HTTP request to another web server (JBOSS - Undertow), both servers are connected using WebSocket (WS) protocol.

Lets explain my problem elaborately.

I have two servers (JBOSS wildfly) called server-A and server-B. Client will always communicate to server-A. Because server-A hosted in public IP. Whereas server-B hosted in a local IP. Hence server-B initiates a WS connection to server-A to share/pass messages.

In this case, if the client wants to access a resource in server-B, client will send request to server-A. Server-A cannot reach server-B directly as server-B hosted in local IP. The only way server-A can redirect the client's HTTP request through existing WS connection to reach server-B. Is it possible to do that?

Note: WS connection will be established between two servers by server-B. Java client is used to establish WS connection

Thanks in advance.